# Band-edge timing error detector, time accumulator

Tags: synchronization, symbol-timing, timing

im trying to implement a band-edge FLL and timing locked loop from this paper (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/261499267_Band_edge_filters_perform_non_data-aided_carrier_and_timing_synchronization_of_software_defined_radio_QAM_receivers).

The FLL works fine but i didnt understand the time accumulator and the interpolator.
Usually the interpolator would decimate the signal to 1 smpl/sym.
In this application it is just a variable delay filter?

How do i pick the optimal sample afterwards?

[image]

Comment: maybe harris' talk helps? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zmjk9NE-3k0

Comment: Thanks. Ive already watched that talk but still clueless.

Comment: Yes the time accumulator and interpolator is the timing recovery loop. The interpolator acts as a variable delay where we select the correct offset to drive the error in the loop to zero (as given by the pos and neg band edge filters in balance doe both carrier (frequency) and time offset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Thanks for your hints and answers. That helped me.

Ive got my code to work now. Its not fine tuned but here is my solution:

-As loop filter i use a PI Filter with a relatively low Ki.
The loop filter is just updated at a 1 Sps/Sym rate when the time accumulator gives an overflow.

-The time accumulator is a modulo interpolation controller

-The interpolator is a farrow structure for cubic interpolation

The IQ plot isn't stationary because the phase isn't locked. But i wont add a following pll anyways because it is a pi/4-DQPSK signal. A bit of phase shifting shouldn't bother me